# Search strings from dict within a data table column values

Tags: r, string, dictionary, search, data.table

There is a data.table dt with a column with text sentences in each row (dt$text).
Then, there is a dictionary with phrases(smaller data.table with phrases column: dict$word and dict$lookup_n column with a number, corresponding to each phrase in a dictionary).

I need to go through each sentence value in dt and if a phrase from dictionary is a part of dt sencence (string), put a phrase in a column dt$yes and put a value from dict$lookup_n column of dict in a dt column dt$lookup_num.
Which is the fastest way to do it?
I know, that I can search text in text string with: grepl("Search_word, "Text_to_search", fixed=TRUE).
I try to do the following (example) bruteforce loop:

```
dt = data.table( text = c('cat, dog books.', 'horse', 'kits fits. mits, bits')) 
dt$yes <- ''
dt$lookup_num <- 0
dt

dict = data.table( word = c('cat, dog ', 'kits'), lookup_n = c(8, 7))

#working!
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(dict)){
    if (dt[i, 'yes'] == '' & grepl(dict[j,word], dt[i,text], fixed=TRUE)) { 
              dt[i,'yes'] <- dict[j,word]
              dt[i,'lookup_num'] <- dict[j,lookup_n]}

  }
}
dt
```

Also, is there any faster way, than looping through dt and dict?

Comment: Can you share the outputs of `dput(dict)` and `dput(dt)`? If large, apply `head(data, 20)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a `data.table` solution. I begin by cleaning `dict`, as it makes no sense to (i) clean the dictionary in each iteration and (ii) to have an untidy dictionary to begin with.

**Code**

```
# Clean the dictionary:
dict = dict[, .(word = unlist(strsplit(gsub(' ', '', word), ','))), keyby = lookup_n]

# Apply matching of word from dict
dt[, yes := sapply(text, function(x){
  cleanx = gsub('[.]|[,]', '', x)
  strings = unlist(strsplit(cleanx, ' '))
  num = dict[word %in% strings, word]
})]

# Extract lookup_n from dict
dt[, lookup_n := lapply(yes, function(y) dict[word %in% y, unique(lookup_n)])]
```

**Result**

```
> dt
                    text     yes lookup_n
1:       cat, dog books. cat,dog        8
2:                 horse                 
3: kits fits. mits, bits    kits        7
```

**Data**

```
dt = data.table( text = c('cat, dog books.', 'horse', 'kits fits. mits, bits')) 
dict = data.table(word = c('cat, dog ', 'kits'), lookup_n = c(8, 7))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!   But if I can not split the sentence by a separator? dt = data.table(
  text = c('cat, dog books.', 'horse', 'kits fits. mits, bits')
)

dict = data.table(
  word = c('cat', 'kits')
  length = c(3, 4)
)

Comment: And also I need to put a length of a word from a dictionary to a dt column 'word_length', if it has the corresponding word in a sentence. Let assume that each sentence may have only one word from dict. Length is just a length of a word in dict, or just a number from dict column for each dict word.

Comment: I have edited my solution accounting for your new data.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But the thing is, that I can not clean the dictionary, I must search for the whole each phase from dictionary. Phrase may include letters, numbers dots, etc, but I need the whole exact phrase. The only delimiter is comma.